# Why do Subversion give some of my UTF-8 text files content type "application/octet-stream"?

Tags: svn, encoding

I got a handful of UTF-8-encoded text files (with text in japanese), and added them to a Subversion repository.

To my surprise, **one** of them got the auto-property `svn:mime-type` set to `application/octet-stream`, while the others did not get any specific encoding information.

The files are valid UTF-8, `file` reports *"UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators"* for all of them.

What is going on here? How does Subversion decide if a file should be treated as binary or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the explanation in the [Subversion sources](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/io.c?view=markup), in `svn_io_is_binary_data`:

```
/* Right now, this function is going to be really stupid.  It's
  going to examine the block of data, and make sure that 15%
  of the bytes are such that their value is in the ranges 0x07-0x0D
  or 0x20-0x7F, and that none of those bytes is 0x00.  If those
  criteria are not met, we're calling it binary.

  NOTE:  Originally, I intended to target 85% of the bytes being in
  the specified ranges, but I flubbed the condition.  At any rate,
  folks aren't complaining, so I'm not sure that it's worth
  adjusting this retroactively now.  --cmpilato  */
```

With Japanese text in UTF-8, most code points will use three bytes, each of which being `>= 0x80`.

The reason not more of my files triggered this behavior was a small preamble with chars in the ASCII range.